# Why isn't there a default polymorphic cloning operator mechanism in c++?

Tags: c++, copy, standards, cloning

I mean, a cloning operator, which by default use the copy constructor and new operator to return a new object. So that **if the declaration in the base class is virtual**, it would automatically provide a polymorphic cloning mechanism (any class should not be virtual by default)

Advantages:

- Avoid doing `Derived * clone() const { return new Derived(*this); }` everywhere
- Allow standard smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or a dedicated copyable one to clone the object without having them rely on a non standard semantic

Whay would be the risk/drawback?

Comment: Because of KISS rule.

Comment: KISS it for C. C++ broke the rule already ;)

Comment: As explained in one of my comments below, I did not find any simple and beautiful solution to this with several levels of inheritance, calling base constructors, etc... Everything is sketchy and ugly.

Answer (score 7):

Because, pay for what you need (if it were automatic for any type, then all classes would be virtual).

There's nothing preventing you from implementing this as a CRTP base class, so language support is unneeded.

You *could* file a proposal adding such a base class (along with a `value_ptr<T, std::default_clone<T> >` and suitable specializations :))

Comment: No, the class would be virtual only if the cloning operator in the base class was declared virtual. As with a destructor.

Comment: What use would a non-virtual clone operation have?

Comment: Your proposal would imply multiple inheritance where it's not needed, if I'm right.

Comment: The use of non-virtual clone would be nothing more than provide the semantic for a standard copyable managed pointer, and avoiding making classes virtual by default...

Comment: Not if you just use the common base class approach, like many popular managed environment already do (CLR, LVM, ParrotVM etc. etc).

Comment: How do you implement cloning without defining a clone function in any derived class, and without multiple inheritance? This could be another question though

Comment: Well, I just read about CRTP polymorphic cloning with several levels of inheritance, constructors, etc... and this is awfully heavy... much more than defining clone everywhere. And still, there is no "standard" cloning semantic which would then be usable in a std::copyable_unique_ptr. Not convincing

Comment: @galinette I think, at this point, you need to define the semantics for your designated clone operation. Of course there's the age-old c++ idiom to have a free function `clone(T*)` and look up the appropriate implementation by ADL. This makes for decoupling, extensibility etc. instead of complicating the type system.